# How Alteryx is deploying data in decentralized way?

Tags: alteryx

From the link :https://reviews.financesonline.com/p/alteryx/, I see the following details

> Alteryx is an advanced data analytics platform intended to serve the
>   needs of business analysts looking for a self-service solution. It
>   contains 3 basic components: Gallery, Designer, and Server, which
>   blend data from external sources and generate comprehensive reports.
>   Each of them, however, can be used separately.
>
> The software structures and evaluates data from multiple external
>   sources, and organizes it into comprehensive insights that can be used
>   for business deciding and shared with multiple internal/external
>   users. **Basically, Alteryx is deploying data in a decentralized way,
>   and eliminating in such way the risk of underestimating it.** At the
>   same time, Alteryx is well-integrated, easy to use, and ran both on
>   premise and in cloud.

Can anyone help me to know what is the text above in bold trying to explain. I am interested to understand it in details with some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of is that the tool can blend just about any kind of data and dump the result to your own local extract... the local extract is "decentralized" in that, obviously it's local, and also you didn't need to rely on some core ETL team to build a process for you (which they would probably dump in a central location). The use of the term "underestimating" probably indicates that, if you're not building in your own insights (say you find something online that you can blend into your analysis), you're "underestimating" the importance of that data.

It's worth noting that your custom extract could be turned into a nightly job and the output could itself be dumped to a centralized database server if desired. So the tool can be used to build centralized assets too.  It really just depends on how you're using it. (With Alteryx this would require either their Desktop Automation, or their Server.)

So... it seems that any self service data blending tool would be capable of the same. What's special about Alteryx? The distinguishing factors will lie elsewhere: number of data types supported, overall functionality and power, performance, built-in examples, ease-of-use, service, support, online community, and perhaps other areas.